# I want do some webscraping of googlenews using BeautifullSoup library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
'''this program is useful for retrieving useful article link from Google news'''

a = input("first name")
str(a)
p = input("last name")
str(p)
t =("https://news.google.co.in/news/section?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=in&q=" + a +
    "+" + p + "&topicsid=FRONTPAGE&ict=tnv3")
print(t)

html = urlopen(t)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
nameList = bsObj.findAll("span",{"class":"titletext"})

for name in nameList:
    print(name.get_text())
```

print("in this code i only fetch the title text , but i want to   fetch    related   link to (so i have to findall  a tag in which href  and titletext is present so how to i fetch both the href and title text at the same time  ")
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent of the `span` tag (`a`) has a `href` attribute. Retrieve the attribute value:

```
...
html = urlopen(t)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
nameList = bsObj.findAll("span",{"class":"titletext"})

for name in nameList:
    print(name.get_text(), name.parent.get('href'))  # <----
```

Comment: Thanks...     Both href and span title text is required  so how i can filter and iterate it.....

Comment: @Pawanvirsingh, Use `if` statement.